# Illegal argument in isolate message: (object is a ReceivePort)

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-isolates

I was trying to write my own worker to process big amount of numbers. And decided to make always working Isolate in which all my data would be processed.

```
class ProjectionWorker {
  
  ...

  Isolate? _isolate;

  ReceivePort? _workerPort;

  Stream? _workerResultStream;

  SendPort? _isolatePort;

  Future<ObjectModel> project(
    ObjectModel model,
    ProjectionData projectionData,
  ) async {
    _workerPort ??= ReceivePort();

    _isolate ??= await Isolate.spawn<SendPort>(
      _isolateScope,
      _workerPort!.sendPort,
      debugName: "flutter_object calculations",
    );

    _workerResultStream ??= _workerPort!.asBroadcastStream();

    _isolatePort ??= await _workerResultStream!.first;

    final Completer<ObjectModel> completer = Completer();

    _workerResultStream!.listen(
      (result) {
        if (result is ObjectModel) completer.complete(result);
      },
    );

    _isolatePort!.send(
      Tuple(
        model,
        projectionData,
      ),
    );

    return completer.future;
  }
}
...

void _isolateScope(SendPort port) async {
  final isolatePort = ReceivePort();

  port.send(isolatePort.sendPort);

  await for (final event in isolatePort) {
    ...

    port.send(result);
  }
}
```

But when I tried to use it in my custom RenderObject, in `paint` method:

```
  Future<void> _projectObject({
    ...
  }) async {
    _projectedObject = await _projectionWorker.project(
      ...
    );
```

I am receiving this:

```
Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s): Illegal argument in isolate message: (object is a ReceivePort)
```

And exception throws from this line of code:

```
...          
_isolatePort!.send(
      Tuple(
        model,
        projectionData,
      ),
    );
...
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invalid argument(s): Illegal argument in isolate message: (object is aReceivePort)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70764481/invalid-arguments-illegal-argument-in-isolate-message-object-is-areceivepor)

Comment: @mmcdon20 unfortunately, no. My function (_isolateScope) is top level and not included in any other class/scope.

Comment: Is there any chance that `ObjectModel` or `ProjectionData` have a `ReceivePort` as a property? (either directly or even transitively like a property of a property)

Comment: @mmcdon20 no. :( It contains only double, Size, Offset…

Comment: Could you provide a [complete minimal example that I could run that would reproduce the error](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? (preferably all the necessary code to run it in one file)

Comment: @mmcdon20 here: https://gist.github.com/samir-a-ts/e093a69219268aeaa23af30bf14f6422

Comment: I tried running the code in the gist, but it is not producing the error message.

Comment: @mmcdon20 that's strange... I would investigate further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out.

It seems stupid, but it worked out for me, so I hope, it would help somebody else.

In my `isolateScope` function `ReceivePort` gets tuple with `ObjectModel` and `ProjectionData`

`ProjectionData` was containing `Size` property in it, and `ObjectModel` had `Color` property.

I cut that both properties out and replaced it with just `double` or `List`.

And it just worked out.

It seems, that isolate somehow gets `RecievePort` by importing `flutter/material.dart`.